# How to copy a file several times into randomly choosen paths within the filesystem?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, random

I have a filesystem and a special file foo. 
I would like the script to choose several times (5,10 or 100) random paths to folders within this filesystem and to copy the file foo into each of them.

[image]

I have an idea, but do not enough to make a real script out of it and do not know if the idea makes sense from viewpoint of performance.

```
   idea in pseudo-script:

    read into variable n how many random paths should be found
    file / -type d > file  # put all existing directory paths into a file
    repeat n-times{
    choose_random_line<file | xargsintosecondargument cp foo 
   /* chose a random line from file and use it as second argument of copy
    command, first is foo. */
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a GNU system:

```
find / -type d -print0 | shuf -zn5 | xargs -r0n1 cp foo
```

(now copying the file to things like /sys or /proc would not make sense or even be possible, you may want to add `-xdev` to only select directories on the file system mounted at `/`).

You could make it compatible with both FreeBSD and GNU with:

```
find / -type d -print0 | sort -zR | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | head -n5 |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | xargs -r0n1 cp foo
```

Comment: what is the purpose of -print0 in find and -z in shuf. Why not find / -type d | shuf -n5 ?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred Because the newline character is as valid as any in a file path. The NUL character is the only one that may not occur in a file path. Those `-print0`, `-z`/`-0`/`--null` options are primarily there to be able to handle file lists reliably.

Comment: The xargs man page says `-i` is deprecated and should be replaced with `-I{}`. Other than that, your answer looks great. Somehow your solution reminds me of http://catb.org/esr/writings/unix-koans/ten-thousand.html

Comment: @kasperd, true, or `xargs -r0n1 cp foo`. Now, I don't see `-i` being removed from GNU xargs any time soon.